# DotNetNuke new pages don't show up

Tags: dotnetnuke, web-publishing

I have added new pages in my DotNetNuke site. Also did some modifications in different pages.

The changes I have made are visible only when I Log in with DNN User account.

After logging out no changes are visible which has been made.

I am doing all the changes locally.

Am I missing on something?

Comment: what you mean by changes  ? what changes you did  have you played with some UsersInfo , Roles in code  ?
You might have checked that if user is looged in then show some specific code ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just assume you're new to these permissions as it's a simple mistake you just made. I always recommend to

1. Set the "All Users" right at the beginning
2. Always use "Inherit from Page..." at the module level

Also note that you should keep an eye on file permissions as well - I wrote a quick blog about that here: http://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/quick-tip-setting-file-folder-permissions-in-dnn-2sxc

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i was missing...
[Permission to view the page by all users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWdaw.png)

When I was adding a new page this check box was not selected by default.